# Converting 1m 51s to a format recognized by Excel as a time

Tags: excel

I'm trying to convert a string to a time format in excel. The data is displayed as `2m 51s`, `0m 4s`, and so on. I'd like to convert this into `2:51` and so on and also would like to be able to pivot the data using those numbers as values. I tried a simple find and replace to remove the `m` and `s` and add in a `:` but it doesn't work when I need to pivot the data as Excel considers that as a date.

Comment: Are there sometimes spaces (e.g. `2m 4s`) and sometimes not (e.g. `2m4s`)? Otherwise, do the values always have the same format?

Comment: There's always a space sorry - it's "0m 4s"

Answer (score 1):

You can use

`=TIME(0,LEFT(A1,(FIND("m",A1,1)-1)),MID(LEFT(A1,FIND("s",A1)-1),FIND("m",A1)+1,LEN(A1)))`

Depending on your settings it may give you an AM/M time but you can change the cell formatting to 'Time' to get 00:02:51.

Answer (score 1):

With data in **E1**, in **F1** enter:

```
=TIMEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE("00:" & E1," ",""),"m",":"),"s",""))
```

and apply proper formatting:

[image]

The formula takes a string like:

```
1m 51s
```

and converts it into:

```
0:1:51
```

this is then processed by the `TIMEVALUE()` function.